# Can a $k$-planar graph have quadratically many maximal cliques?

Tags: graph-theory

Can a $k$-planar graph have quadratically many maximal cliques?

I know that any planar or $1$-planar graph $G=(V,E)$ has only $O(|V|)$ maximal cliques, but is there anything known about this question for $k>1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this study has only just begun.

The following statement came from Literature [1].

> For $k ≥ 3$, not even the **maximum number of edges** is known for
> $n$-vertex $k$-planar graphs, so counting larger cliques is likely to
> be an extremely difficult problem.

[1] Gollin J P, Hendrey K, Methuku A, et al. Counting cliques in 1-planar graphs[J]. European Journal of Combinatorics, 2023, 109: 103654.

In fact, Bekos et al. [2] proved that a $3$-planar graph with $n$-vertices has at most $5.5n-10.5$ edges. But we do not know if the bound is tight.

[2] Bekos M A, Kaufmann M, Raftopoulou C N. On the density of non-simple 3-planar graphs[C]//International Symposium on Graph Drawing and Network Visualization. Springer, Cham, 2016: 344-356.

Gollin et al. also give this conjecture:

**Conjecture.** For $n ≥ 7$, the maximum number of triangles in an $n$-vertex 2-planar graph is at most $(17n − 49)/2$.

The bound in the conjecture  is achieved by the 2-planar graphs formed by stitching copies of $K_7$ together. This stitching is possible since $K_7$ has a $2$-drawing with two facial triangles.
[image]

An $n$-vertex 1-planar graph with $4n − 8$ edges is called an optimal 1-planar graph. An open problem for optimal 1-planar graphs that I love is as follows:

**Problem.** Let $n$ and $t$ be positive integers with $t ∈ \{3, 4, 5\}$ and $n ≥ 10$. What is the maximum number of subgraphs isomorphic to $K_t$
in an $n$-vertex 1-planar graph with $4n − 8$ edges?

To address this problem, I recently worked on the properties of optimal 1-plane graphs, although some are not directly relevant. (Some other progress is being organized)

- L.C. Zhang, Y.Q. Huang, The reducibility of optimal 1-planar graphs with respect to the lexicographic product [J]. arXiv preprint arXiv:2211.14733, 2022.